# Converting a String to a Char array and then returning only the even indexes of the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I'm new to Java and I want to write a method that converts a String to a Char array and returns this Char array but only the chars in the even numbered indexes.

I tried something like

```
public char[] collectEvenChars(String str) {

        char [] chr = str.toCharArray();
        char [] temp;
        int k=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < chr.length;i++)

        {        
            if ( i % 2 == 0)

                k++;
            }
        }
```

And then somehow trying to use k as size for the temp char array but that doesn't work. I've also tried using a while loop

```
char[] collectEvenChars(String str){
    char [] chr = str.toCharArray();
    char [] temp = new char [chr.length];
    int i = 0;

    while (i<chr.length & i % 2 == 0){

        temp [i] = chr [i];



    }

    return temp;
```

And there is an error saying "expected.length = 5, actual.length = 9" so it has to do something with the return of the array but I can't change the size of the array if I initialize it in the beginning and returning it in the loop doesn't work because then the loop doesn't loop. I'm pretty much helpless here. If it was void this would be easy but since I have to return an array I'm pretty much helpless.

Comment: you didnt count "i" up. int i = 0; will  stay 0

Comment: You haven't posted the code that doesn't work, in the first snippet. The second snippet would be run ad infinitum since you never increment i. But think about it. Say you have 2 million characters. And you want only the characters at even indices. How many characters will the result array have? Do you really need to count until 2 million to know?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things - you can just run over the even indexes:

```
char[] collectEvenChars(String str){
    char[] result = new char[(str.length() + 1) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        result[i / 2] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) said, you are over-complicating things. It is much easier than you think. Instead of creating two new char arrays, just use the string's length for the condition and change your iterator to `i += 2`. You can use `String#charAt`  for the indices instead of constructing a new  array:

```
public static char[] getEvenIndices(String str) {

    String newString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
        newString += str.charAt(i);
    }

    return newString.toCharArray();
}
```

It works with Strings of any length. I printed the array as a String:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getEvenIndices("EvenIndicesOfThisString.")));
```

and got a satisfying result:

```
[E, e, I, d, c, s, f, h, s, t, i, g]
```